Python Polars Zip several columns of type of List
I have two columns of type pl.List(pl.List(str)) that I want to append elementwise with a separator like ;.
Given a dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A":[["Hi", "my", "is"],["I am"]],
    "B":[["there", "name", "mr.x"], ["smart"]]
})

shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ A                  ┆ B                         │
│ ---                ┆ ---                       │
│ list[str]          ┆ list[str]                 │
╞════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ ["Hi", "my", "is"] ┆ ["there", "name", "mr.x"] │
│ ["I am"]           ┆ ["smart"]                 │
└────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘

I expect the output to be
shape: (2, 1)
┌────────────────────────────────────┐
│ A                                  │
│ ---                                │
│ list[str]                          │
╞════════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["Hi;there", "my;name", "is;mr.x"] │
│ ["I am;smart"]                     │
└────────────────────────────────────┘

How can I do this natively?

Is the description wrong? The example only has list[str] columns but the description says you have list[list[str]] columns.

Straightforward way of doing would be some way of explode()/calculate/implode().

pl.DataFrame.with_row_index() to assign index so we can group by it later.
pl.Expr.explode() to explode lists into rows.
pl.Expr.implode() to implode lists back.
pl.Expr.over() to run the calculation within each row.

(
    df
    .with_row_index()
    .select(
        (pl.col.A.explode() + ';' + pl.col.B.explode())
        .implode()
        .over("index")
        .alias("A")
    )
)

# or
# (
#     df
#     .with_row_index()
#     .explode("A","B")
#     .select(pl.col.index, A = pl.col.A + ';' + pl.col.B)
#     .group_by("index")
#     .agg(pl.all())
#     .drop("index")
# )

shape: (2, 1)
┌────────────────────────────────────┐
│ A                                  │
│ ---                                │
│ list[str]                          │
╞════════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["Hi;there", "my;name", "is;mr.x"] │
│ ["I am;smart"]                     │
└────────────────────────────────────┘

Alternatively, you can do some way of list.eval() approach, but to do that you need to have all the information you need within the list.

pl.concat_list() to concat A and B into one continuous list.
pl.Expr.list.eval() to run expression for elements of list.
pl.Expr.shift() to shift elements of list.

(
    df
    .select(
        A = 
        pl.concat_list(pl.col.A, pl.col.B, pl.col.A.list.len())
        .list.eval(
            pl.element() + ';' +
            pl.element().shift(-pl.element().last().cast(pl.Int32))
        )
        .list.head(pl.col.A.list.len())
    )
)

shape: (2, 1)
┌────────────────────────────────────┐
│ A                                  │
│ ---                                │
│ list[str]                          │
╞════════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["Hi;there", "my;name", "is;mr.x"] │
│ ["I am;smart"]                     │
└────────────────────────────────────┘

Or you can use the fact that Structs actually implement string per-field addition, so you just need to convert list to Struct and back.

pl.Expr.list.to_struct() to convert both A and B to structs.
pl.Expr.repeat_by() to create a list of ; so you can use it in calculation.
pl.Expr.struct.unnest() to unnest the struct into columns.
pl.concat_list() to concat the columns into list.

(
    df
    .select(
        pl.col.A.list.to_struct() +
        pl.lit(";").repeat_by(pl.col.A.list.len()).list.to_struct() +
        pl.col.B.list.to_struct()
    )
    .select(
        pl.concat_list(pl.col.A.struct.unnest()).list.drop_nulls()
        # or
        # pl.concat_list(pl.col.A.struct.field("*")).list.drop_nulls()
    )
)

shape: (2, 1)
┌────────────────────────────────────┐
│ A                                  │
│ ---                                │
│ list[str]                          │
╞════════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["Hi;there", "my;name", "is;mr.x"] │
│ ["I am;smart"]                     │
└────────────────────────────────────┘


Do both of these also work when the sublists are of different length? Each list-pair to be zipped is always of equal length tho. I have edited the question to illustrate it a bit better.

no, second one is a bit limited, so only will work on fixed list lengths, working on something better now

@mavex857 updated, not sure if it's going to be better performing though
